# Custom URL Protocol avoiding security warnings

Tags: protocols, custom-protocol, url-protocol

I'm researching whether it would be possible to use Custom URL Application Protocols (such as custom://) to launch my application but it looks like all implementations modify the HKCR.  This causes some nasty security warnings (I believe because of UAC).  Does anyone know if it's possible to install Custom URL Protocols as the HKCU level?  Or an alternate way to avoid these warnings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use the same information you found for HKCR, but use the following path:

HKCU\Software\Classes

Comment: For those that don't know the method - you can find that here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx